# Regexp equivalent for floating number in matlab

Tags: matlab

I'd like to know how `regexp` is used for floating numbers or is there any other function to do this.

For example, the following returns `{'2', '5'}` rather than `{'2.5'}`.

```
nums= regexp('2.5','\d+','match')
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Regular expressions are a tool for low-level text parsing and they have no concept of numeric datatypes. If you will want to parse decimals, you need to consider what characters compose a decimal number and design a regexp to explicitly match all of those characters.

Your example only returns the `'2'` and `'5'` because your pattern only matches characters that are digits (`\d`). To handle the decimal numbers, you need to explicitly include the `.` in your pattern. The following will match any number of digits followed by 0 or 1 radix points and 0 or more numbers after the radix point.

```
regexp('2.5', '\d+\.?\d*', 'match')
```

This assumes that you'll always have a leading digit (i.e. not `'.5'`)

Alternately, you may consider using something like [`textscan`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/textscan.html) or [`sscanf`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/sscanf.html) instead to parse your string which is going to be more robust than a custom regex since they are aware of different numeric datatypes.

```
C = textscan('2.5', '%f');
C = sscanf('2.5', '%f');
```

If your string *only* contains this floating point number, you can just use `str2double`

```
val = str2double('2.5');
```

Comment: Or just [`str2double`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/str2double.html), assuming the string is known to only contain a floating point value.

Comment: Thank you so much @Suever. `regexp('2.5', '\d+\.?\d*', 'match')` worked precisely!

Answer (score 1):

@Suever answer has already been accepted, anyway here is some more complete one that should accept all sorts of floating points syntaxes (including NaN and +/-Inf by default):

```
% Regular expression for capturing a double value
function [s] = cdouble(supportPositiveInfinity, supportNegativeInfinity, 
supportNotANumber)
%[
    if (nargin < 3), supportNotANumber = true; end
    if (nargin < 2), supportNegativeInfinity = true; end
    if (nargin < 1), supportPositiveInfinity = true; end

    % A double
    s = '[+\-]?(?:(?:\d+\.\d*)|(?:\.\d+)|(?:\d+))(?:[eE][+\-]?\d+)?'; %% This means a numeric double

    % Extra for nan or [+/-]inf
    extra = '';
    if (supportNotANumber), extra = ['nan|' extra]; end
    if (supportNegativeInfinity), extra = ['-inf|' extra]; end
    if (supportPositiveInfinity), extra = ['inf|\+inf|' extra]; end

    % Adding capture
    if (~isempty(extra))
        s = ['((?i)(?:', extra, s, '))']; % (?i) => Locally case-insensitive for captured group
    else
        s = ['(', s, ')'];
    end    
%]
end
```

Basically above pattern says:

1. Eventually start with '+' or '-' sign
2. Then followed by either

   - One or more digits followed by a dot and eventually zero to many digits
   - A dot followed by one or more digits
   - One or more digits only
3. Then followed by exponant pattern, that is:

   - 'e' or 'E' (eventually followed with '+' or '-') and one or more digits

Pattern is later completed with support of `Inf`, `+Inf`, `-Inf` and `NaN` in case insensitive way. Finally everthing is enclosed between `(` and `)` for capturing purpose.

Here is some online test example: https://regex101.com/r/K87z6e/1

Or you can test in matlab:

```
>> regexp('Hello 1.235 how .2e-7 are INF you +.7 doing ?', cdouble(), 'match')

ans = 

    '1.235'    '.2e-7'    'INF'    '+.7'
```